# Android: Setting width percentage of view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a RelativeLayout, and want to center the orange bar below in the center and fill up 90% of the width. I know this is possible to do using a LinearLayout using percentage, but how do I do so with a RelativeLayout?

Do I have to programatically calculate how wide is the screen (in dp), and set this 90% of this as the width of the orange view?

In short, I want something like this, where the orange bar takes up 90% of the screen centered in the middle using a RelativeLayout, without hardcoding x and y coordinates, so that it works on all screen densities. (The dark bars in the edge are the edge of the phone)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but worth a try :)
Please redesign your layout structure like below:

```
<LinearLayout[with 90% width]>
    <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           ...
         <!--this will fill up its parent i.e above LinearLayout which is 90% of the screen width -->
     >
           <!--child views goes here.. -->
     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: actually, this was what I was looking for. I'm a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

*Use new percentage support library*

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.0.0'
```

*See below example*

```
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

*For More Info * [Tutorial1](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en) [Tutorial2](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/percentrelativelayout-in-android/) [Tutorial3](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)